# How to Read text file and pass it to list in c#?

Tags: c#, list, parameter-passing, file-read

I have declared a list i-e

```
List<double> list = new List<double>();
```

Initially list is empty. By reading from a text file, I am storing the data into list. The code which I have tried yet is:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\MusicExaminer\\frequencies.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
      //Console.WriteLine(line);
      list.Add(double.Parse(line));                        
}
file.Close();

//print the list
foreach (double s in list)
{
     Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

List is updated. It is assigned values same as the text file. I have a method named notes(`List<double> list`) which accept that list as parameter.
inside the method it read list items one by one and print.
but when i'm calling the method I do not get any output. when i manually store values to list and call to the function notes(list) like this I'm getting the output which I expected. How to solve this?

[image: Here is my Notes function code]

If the list value between 261 && 262 it draw Musical sysmbol C in the incipit Viewer. (Notation Sheet)

Comment: What is inside text file which you are reading?

Comment: It is having some double values. like 261.63
293.45
256.36

Comment: They are separated by lines?

Comment: yes. 261.63 is in new line. and 293.45 in next line. like wise. each line is having 1 value.

Comment: Is there any error or exception in your code?

Comment: No Errors. Application is Running.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a simple console application to reproduce your behavior and this code is working on my PC, please check it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var list = new List<double>();

                using (var file = new StreamReader("C:\\MusicExaminer\\frequencies.txt"))
                {
                    var line = string.Empty;

                    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        list.Add(Convert.ToDouble(line, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                    }
                }

                Notes(list);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Notes(List<double> list)
        {
            foreach (var s in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s.ToString("F");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the execution result

[image]

Comment: Looks like your output doesn't match the input.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen I suppose you're talking about the format, I have updated the code showing the text using InvariantCulture formatting.

Comment: Thanks @Jorge Ramirez. Actually I'm getting values from text and store it to list.
Inside Notes(list) function what is happening is I compare the values and create musical notations and display it in the music notation sheet.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = File.ReadLines("C:\\MusicExaminer\\frequencies.txt")
            .Select(line => double.Parse(line))
            .ToList();

        for (item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file has only decimal numbers and each number is on single line then try this code:

```
var result = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\MusicExaminer\frequencies.txt").Select(x => double.Parse(x.Trim())).ToList();
```

Comment: Why is this better? It requires buffering the entire file in memory before parsing. For a large file this will be horribly inefficient.

Comment: I think very very big text file can contains 10 to 20 MB in your case, this doesn't matter. But your code also seem correct but I am wondering what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to write the result to the console you can just do this:

```
File
    .ReadLines("C:\\MusicExaminer\\frequencies.txt")
    .Select(double.Parse)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All of you.
Finally I found The Mistake.
I Forgot to Refresh the Incipit Viewer.(Notation Sheet)
After Calling Notes() Function I Added This Line.

incipitViewer.Refresh();

Now It is working fine.